# Error al instalar Pillow en ubuntu 15.10 32 bits

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
$ pip install pillow 
Failed building wheel for pillow
...
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
...
```

Comment: Por favor, añade a la pregunta la información completa del problema como la versión de python que usas y la salida del fichero `pip.log` que encontrarás en el directorio `.pip`. Así mismo, intenta formatear el texto de la pregunta usando marcas markdown.

Comment: También, indica si estás usando algún ambiente virtual ya que si no lo estás usando tendrías que instalar usando `sudo`

Comment: gracias amigo por la observaciones, ya hice lo que me recomendabas....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de instalar Pillow, asegúrate de haber instalado las dependencias:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools
$ sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

Luego, intenta la instalación de Pillow nuevamente en tu `virtualenv`:

```
$ pip install Pillow
```

### Referencias

- [Pillow installation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: al parecer todo esta en orden con las dependencias....

Comment: gracias amigo, pues todo lo que colocaste es una solución, ya que solo bastaba con reiniciar mi pc y listo.. gracias saludos.